# How to disable MediaElementPlayer's buffer

Tags: mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I unfortunately have multiple players on the same page and would like to disable the auto load/buffer of the songs being presented.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting `preload="none"` on the audio/video tags in question?

Comment: thanks a bunch, I some how missed this in all my googling.  Some how i didn't think to use "preload" as a keyword.